# Angular 2: Cannot set property 'location' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am still pretty new to Angular 2 and cant get around this problem.

I am trying to get the users current location and safe his coordinates in a variable called "location". When trying to accomplish this I recieve the following error message:
[image]

The code looks like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';


@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './app.home.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.home.css']
})
export class HomeAppComponent {
  //restaurants: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  zoom: number = 8;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  location: any = {};

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
     //this.restaurants = af.database.list('/restaurants');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition);
     }
  }

  setPosition(position) {
     this.location = position.coords;
     console.log(position.coords);
  }

}
```

When setting propery location to something like:

```
location.lat = 32;
location.lng = 53;
```

It is possible to output their values in the constructor, but in the setPosition function its null.

What am I doing wrong....

Comment: paste the code as a code block. Avoid screenshot of code

Comment: getCurrentPostion takes a parameterized function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call using arrow function like so:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>this.setPosition(pos))
```

or if it does not send a parameter,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(()=>this.setPosition())
```

Answer (score 2):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition)`

should be

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition.bind(this))
```

Your `this` is not refering to the page inside `setPosition`

Comment: Thank you very much...working with this confuses me from time to time

Comment: @kevj no problem. I suggest you to take a look at this great post :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485